Estimate of a Weil height
Found in a textbook. Since I am learning heights now, I thought it is a good exercise to pratice. But I am far away to solve it. Let $y\in{\overline{\mathbb Q}}^\times$. Prove that there exists $C>0$ that for for all $n\in\mathbb N$, the Weil height of $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{y^k}{k!}$ is less than $C\delta^nn!$ where $\delta$ is the least positive integer such that $\delta y$ is an algebraic integer.
By using Mahler measure and sub-multiplicativity of Weil height, I manage to obtain only a bound in $n!^2$. Can anyone help to improve in what it is requested.
Thanks in advance

Not sure I understand the problem: if $a_n$ is the desired sum, $\delta^nn!a_n$ is an algebraic integer less than or equal to $e^{|y|}\delta^nn!$.

It is an exercise for beginners. So if you think it is trivial, that's normal :D But for very beginners, it is not (at least for me).  Can  you expand your answer? I obtained $H(\alpha_n\delta^nn!)\le\delta^nn!e^{\mathrm{house}(y)}$ from Mahler measure. From this, I did not manage to obtain the requested bound.
